# Inconsistent NTP settings on Windows Servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, ntp

I'm seeing this odd behaviour on some Windows servers we have:

The output of NTP configuration includes these lines:

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /configuration
NtpClient (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Local)
Type: NT5DS (Local)
```

On the other hand, when I query the "source" with "w32tm /query /source" I get this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /source
Local CMOS Clock
```

I cannot understand why there is an inconsistency of one setting showing NT5DS and the other showing Local CMOS Clock. Anybody would like to shed some light into this?

Comment: I see no inconsistency in any of the data that you provided. What makes you think that there is?

Comment: Inconsistency is that the type of the source is "NT5DS" which means that the server is supposed to get the time from the domain hierarchy, but it does not do that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779145(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I agree that you are configured to sync from a domain controller, however you are failing to do so. This might be because of lack of network connectivity, for example. Review the System event log for events from Windows Time to see why you are failing to receive valid time data from a domain controller.

Comment: There is no problems with network connectivity, both are on the same subnet with no external or internal firewalls in between them. I have confirmed this with w32tm /stripchart command and I do get NTP responses from the DCs. IT's just looking at the wrong place.

Comment: And if the System event log doesn't give you enough detail, then you can enable verbose w32time logging: `w32tm /debug /enable /file:c:\W32Time\w32time.log /size:10000000 /entries:0-300`

Comment: That was actually very helpful. I think I see the problem. I'll update you ASAP.